# Change URL using JavaScript history API without replacing previous URL

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I am trying to make something like google maps direction module, but I am stuck with URL part of the module. The problem which I am facing is that I want to change URL every time user selects something from auto suggested result and because of it, a new history is created every time. So pressing back button generates URL which I do not wish. I also used `replacesate()` but it changed my previous url. Please refer google maps to understand my question.

The way I am changing URL is

```
window.history.pushState("", title, newUrl);
```

Suppose my first search was for Delhi to agra. Then I searched for some other combination. When selected, I am changing the URL. Pressing back button does not take me to result for delhi to agra rather it shows me results for url changed when selected. I hope I have explained my problem.

Function used to change URL on every selection is

```
var call_url = function(title, req_url, inputId)
{
  if(!title) 
  {
    title = req_url.replace('place-','');
  }
  var url = window.location.toString().split('/');
  var curl = url.slice(-1)[0];
  if(curl != req_url)
  {
    if($.inArray("direction", url) !== -1 || url[4].indexOf("direction-") !== -1)  // check to handle direction url
    {
      var elementId = ($(':focus')[0]) ? $(':focus')[0].id : inputId;
      if(elementId && (elementId == 'auto_start' || elementId == 'auto_end' || elementId.indexOf('via') !== -1))
      {
        newUrl = directionUrl(req_url, url[4], elementId);
      }
      else
      {
        newUrl = req_url;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      newUrl = req_url;
      document.title = title.replace(/\-/g,", ").replace(/\+/g," ");
    }
    window.history.pushState("", title, newUrl);
  }
};
```

Comment: Your question is difficult to answer as it doesn't contain your code. You'll need to post your code so that people can look at it and point out where the problem is. It's preferred that you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You can use the [edit] button to update your question. Good luck!

Comment: You can first cache these auto suggested state in a list, and listen to the popstate event, check if the state is in the list, if true, navigate back one more step.

Comment: @Shelvin Are you suggesting me to use html 5 application cache

Comment: @MustanishAltamash, simply use a array to store the states, eg: var historyStates = [state1, state2, state3], add state to the list when you invoke the pushState method, then  listen to the popstate event, check if the state is in the array, if true, navigate back last state. And don't forget to clear the unused state in the array.